# Почему вызов метода не возвращает значение из forEach внутри него? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ооп

есть такой метод:

```
  getGridSize() {
    Object.keys(this.options.mq).forEach((size) => {
      if (window.matchMedia(this.options.mq[size]).matches) {
        return size;
      }

      return 'desktop';
    });
  }
```

Мне нужно чтоб сам метод при вызове возвращал то значение которое в return внутри метода, сейчас оно возвращает undefined при вызове метода.

Comment: потому что `forEach` это `дляВсех` а не `покаНе`. возьмите `.find()` или цикл. а `undefined` вообще потоум что у вас сама функция `getGridSize` не имеет оператора `return`

Comment: на цикл es линтер ругается, и вопрос в том почему return не возвращает если метод вызывать

Comment: а как мне сделать чтоб метод возвращал значение из внутреннего return? мне оно нужно

Comment: если вам нужно первое совпадение по условию, то что-то вроде `return Object.keys(...).find(size => ...) || 'desktop';`